# Fetch seems to execute on client in React

Tags: reactjs, frontend, web-frontend

I am building a web application in React, and I am doing a fetch request in `componentDidMount`, e.g.:

```js
fetch('http://localhost:8080')
            .then(currencies => currencies.json())
            .then(currencies => this.setState({
                currencies, loading: false
            }))
            .catch(err => console.log(err));
```

This works on my machine. I want to deploy the app to Kubernetes, and so I change `localhost` to name of service, e.g. `http://history:8080`.

When I deploy that, it seems that upon GET on frontend, the frontend loads in my browser and then tries to GET `history:8080` from my personal laptop.

Is that true, or am I misunderstanding my errors?

If that's true, how can I force the fetch on the backend? I need the request to be performed by the container, and then I need to be just served the page.

Comment: Are you running Kubernetes on your laptop?

Comment: @MaazSyedAdeeb no, it's a dev cluster in the cloud

Comment: `componentDidMount` only fires on client not server side

Comment: @JoeLloyd ah. Where should my fetch apis be to fire on server side? Is there a standard place?

Comment: yeah i dono your setup. its much more complex. I dont know what kubernetes is but if thats your backend there will be some best practices for server side fetching there. otherwise you have to make a router in node and thats a pain. Or use Next js, its very ez with next

Comment: @JoeLloyd Are there any component methods that fire on server? Constructor, or something similar?

Comment: yeah there are some but deprecated. shouldn't use them, check out the lifecycle methods api [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html)

Comment: @JoeLloyd Thank you. Feel free to make it an answer, I'll mark it as valid.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using react-router? Sometimes there is a clash between client routes and server routes if they are the same url/endpoint , and then the solution is to add “/api” etc.. before the back end routes and that’s how they won’t clash.

Answer (score 0):

Read this section in reactjs website
https://reactjs.org/blog/2018/03/27/update-on-async-rendering.html#fetching-external-data

> When supporting server rendering, it’s currently necessary to provide
>   the data synchronously – componentWillMount was often used for this
>   purpose but the constructor can be used as a replacement. The upcoming
>   suspense APIs will make async data fetching cleanly possible for both
>   client and server rendering.